# jms point to point or JMS publisher and subscriber

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic

I am a novice user for jmeter.

In my company i need to do load testing. I am using Hermes JMS to send request and response using the queues. So what should I use in jmeter, jms point to point or JMS publisher and subscriber. And I also want to set up the ftp location to get the files.

I tried both of those but getting the error in jndi properties:

> "ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"

I am not exactly sure how can I set up the queues that I am using in hermes.

---

How can I setup the JNDI settings? Or its default because I was reading online and everyone has Initial Context Factory as `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` and what about the queues do I need to provide my own queues or that's the default as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you **have the 'activemq-all-[version].jar' file in the *lib* folder of JMeter** so that when you set the **'Initial Context Factory' property to 'org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory'** (as well as the 'QueueConnection Factory' resource to 'ConnectionFactory') in the JMS Sampler the latter is found and initiated by JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using queues, you'll want to use JMS point to point. JMS publisher and subscriber uses JMS topics. If the queues already exist in ActiveMQ (and they appear to since you can see them in Hermes), you'll need to configure JMeter to use those. It sounds like your JNDI settings are incorrect and JMeter cannot find the JNDI name you're telling it to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 2nd part of your question: when using a JMS Publisher, you can use the `dynamicQueues/` prefix for your destination when creating queues, `dynamicTopics/` for topics, e.g. `dynamicQueues/my.testqueue`